# Using Arrays on Conway's Game of Life

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, logic, 2d

I have hit a wall on my newest lab for school. We're remaking Conway's game of life using arrays and they want us to make one array as the original and make the changes happen in another array.

where I'm stuck at is the neighbor logic though! im not quite sure on the syntax, or the implementation really, to check to see if a neighbor, or next index in the array, is alive or not.

here's my source code so far(had to copy and paste due to low rep)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class life {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game();
    }

    public static void Game() {
        char [][] board; //original board
        board = new char[5][5];

        char [][] boardCopy;
        board = new char [5][6]; // board to use as a replacement.

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { //loops that makes the original board.
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 5; j++) {
                int x = (int)(Math.random() * 11);
                if (x <= 5) { board[i][j] = 'X'; }
                if(x > 5) { board[i][j] = '.'; }
            }
        }

        printTable(board);
    }

    public static void printTable(char[][] x){
        //prints the arrays in a table. 
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: You never use `boardCopy` after defining it. That could be a good place to start. After that, think about which array indices would constitute a neighbor in Conway's game by laying out your board on grid paper.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to understand this problem is to take a sample element from your array, let's call it

```
board[i][j]
```

The way I would picture it is the following:

Any random element in the MIDDLE of the array (not on the edges or corners) has 8 neighbors, either alive or dead. Just picture a square surrounded by equal-sized squares. It has a neighbor to the left, right, top, bottom, top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right.

Your job is to merely cycle through these 8 elements and check their status (isAlive() method would be logical).

So how do you represent each element in code? Will consider the neighbor to the right. He's on the same "row" as your array (we called it i), but he's one "column" to the right (j + 1). Therefore, he would be represented as

```
board[i][j + 1]
```

Similarly, the neighbor to the left would be

```
board[i][j - 1]
```

Does that make sense?

Then to finish the project you would simply have to make sure that the element whose neighbors you are checking is not on of the edges, and if it is: make sure not to check past the boundaries of your array or you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.